# Summing up a col and storing the value at the last index in a new column in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
     col1  
df=   1
      2
      3
      4
```

How do I get the following in R

```
      col1   col2
df=    1      
       2
       3
       4      10(total of col1)
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah. It does'nt not answer my question

Comment: Ok.reopened....

Comment: Did you check my below answer, did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:4)
df$col2 <- NA
df$col2[nrow(df)] <- sum(df$col1, na.rm = TRUE)
df
#  col1 col2
#1    1   NA
#2    2   NA
#3    3   NA
#4    4   10
```

Keeping other values in `col2` as `NA` instead of blanks since blanks would turn the column to character.